# Singleton Object State in PHP Based Web Application

Tags: php, singleton

An object created with singleton pattern can only have one instance, so, does it works with PHP based web applications?

**Questions:**

1. Is singleton object created for each visitor on application or is it shared among all the visitors?
2. If one Singleton object is shared among multiple visitors then where and how it is stored on server?
3. If different singleton object is generated for different visitor then how each page of website knows that it had to use same instance of singleton object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when people talk about singletons in PHP they mean per request cycle. So during the evaluation of one request only one instance of the singleton class can exist. That means each visitor gets their own instance and every visit as well (so the same visitor on two subsequent visits gets two different instances as well).

Similar concepts with bigger/longer scope exist though. The Flow Framework knows something called a session scope, so the same visitor gets the same instance across visits by storing the "singleton" object in the session data, but also that is obviously limited. Unless you would use something like an app server in Java (like Tomcat) there is not a good way to have a singleton for the whole application (so for every visitor and visit the same instance). I am not sure if appserver.io has this feature by now.